# Yii2: Use scopes of realtion in with() of ActiveRecord

Tags: php, activerecord, scope, yii2

In Yii1 I could do something like this:

```
$posts=Post::model()->with(array(
    'comments'=>array(
        'scopes'=>array('recently','approved')
    ),
))->findAll();
```

Is there a way to call a scope of a relation in the callback function of with() in Yii2?

```
Customer::find()->with([
    'orders' => function ($query) {
        $query->andWhere('status = 1');
    },
    'country',
])->all();
```

Answer (score 5):

A clean solution is by overriding the model's `find()` method to use a custom [ActiveQuery](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html) class :

```php
class Order extends yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function find()
    {
        return new OrderQuery(get_called_class());
    }
}

class OrderQuery extends yii\db\ActiveQuery
{
    public function payed()
    {
        return $this->andWhere(['status' => 1]);
    }
}
```

then you can use it like :

```php
$customers = Customer::find()->with([
    'orders' => function($q) {
        $q->payed();
    }
])->all();
```

You can also chain many of them like Yii 1 scopes. 
In this post you'll find more examples on how to use [ActiveQuery](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html) class to build **Named Scopes** :

[Yii2 : ActiveQuery Example and what is the reason to generate ActiveQuery class separately in Gii?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948917/yii2-activequery-example-and-what-is-the-reason-to-generate-activequery-class/31950149#31950149)