# Yii2 : ActiveQuery Example and what is the reason to generate ActiveQuery class separately in Gii?

Tags: php, yii2, gii

Could you provide an example usage. Description will be highly appreciated. I can not find a good example for it.

[image: ActiveQuery in Gii]

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The [Active Query](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html) represents a DB query associated with an [Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html) class. It is usually used to override the default `find()` method of a specific model where it will be used to generate the query before sending to DB :

```php
class OrderQuery extends ActiveQuery
{
     public function payed()
     {
        return $this->andWhere(['status' => 1]);
     }

     public function big($threshold = 100)
     {
        return $this->andWhere(['>', 'subtotal', $threshold]);
     }

}
```

If you worked before with Yii 1 then this is what replaces [Yii 1.x Named Scopes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes) in Yii2. All you have to do is to override the `find()` method in your **model** class to use the ActiveQuery class above :

```php
// This will be auto generated by gii if 'Generate ActiveQuery' is selected
public static function find()
{
    return new \app\models\OrderQuery(get_called_class());
}
```

Then you can use it this way :

```php
$payed_orders      =   Order::find()->payed()->all();

$very_big_orders   =   Order::find()->big(999)->all();

$big_payed_orders  =   Order::find()->big()->payed()->all();
```

---

A different use case of the same **ActiveQuery** class defined above is by using it when defining **relational data** in a related *model* class like:

```php
class Customer extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    ...

    public function getPayedOrders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::className(),['customer_id' => 'id'])->payed();
    }
}
```

Then you can eager load *customers* with their respective *payed orders* by doing :

```php
$customers = Customer::find()->with('payedOrders')->all();
```

Comment: gem of an answer. So well described. Loved it thank you :)

Comment: pleasure is mine @noc2spamツ I'm glad it helped. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to modify the Select statement as well?

Comment: Yes @geilt [select](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#select()-detail) and [addSelect](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#addSelect()-detail) are [ActiveQuery](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html) methods we can use. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43840406/yii2-how-to-set-scenario-in-dataprovider/43848957#43848957