# How to filter data in a Yii 2 model?

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have a table Company and one of it's field is status. It may have one of two values: open or closed.

I've generated a Model using Gii.

How can i filter data in a model so that I'll see only companies with "closed" status on my `r=company/index` page?

Usually i'd write a query like `"SELECT * FROM company WHERE status = 'closed'"` but i don't know where to write it in Yii 2. All these MVC stuff makes me mad. Can't understand anything, really.

Comment: There are a lot of documentation on Yii site about framework structure. Read about ActiveRecord http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html

Comment: you can also build an `ActiveQuery` for it so you can do : `Company::find()->closed()->all();` (check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948917/yii2-activequery-example-and-what-is-the-reason-to-generate-activequery-class/31950149#31950149)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

You can filter the model search results with the following code in your controller:

```
$companies = Company::find()
        ->where(['status' => 'closed'])
        ->all();
```

Comment: Should I be filtering data in controller or in model?

Comment: You should do it inside your controller. Also, are you using CRUD generated with gii?

Comment: @marche yes, gii generated

Comment: You should filter data in controller

Comment: `where` condition should be an array