# How to extend a model conditionally

Tags: activerecord, model, yii2

I'm not sure of the right terminology here but I think this is quite easy to do in Yii2 but I can't seem to find how.

I want to have a class `Location` which extends `ActiveRecord` but I have two types of locations. To handle this I will have a field called `location.type` which is enum `('store','campus')`. Then I want to create two models that extend Location named Store and Campus with each only returning results based on the `type` field.

I saw that I think Yii1.x allowed a model method named find() that might work like this:

```
public model find()
{
    return $this->andWhere(['type' => 'store']);
}
```

But this doesn't work in Yii2. Is what I'm doing sound like the correct approach? How can I best achieve this?

Edit:
I've found that I should be using ActiveQuery as described here*. However the method active() (or whatever method I name it) is not called. I seem to be missing something.

*http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#customizing-query-classes

Answer (score 1):

OK, what I needed to do was a lot simpler. I just needed to override the model's find() method like so:

```
public static function find()
{
    return parent::find()->where(['type' => store']);
}
```

Comment: yes that is the simplest way but if you need a better approach to handle more complex cases then I would recommand this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948917/yii2-activequery-example-and-what-is-the-reason-to-generate-activequery-class/31950149#31950149