# REST Api with QueryParamAuth authenticator - Yii2

Tags: rest, yii2, restful-authentication

I'm trying to create rest api for my application to get the data in my android app. This is my controller

```
<?php

namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\filters\auth\QueryParamAuth;

/**
 * Tk103 Controller API
 */
class Tk103Controller extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'api\modules\v1\models\Tk103CurrentLocation';  

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => QueryParamAuth::className(),
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }  

}
```

I added `access_token` column in my **user** table, implemented `findIdentityByAccessToken()` in User Model and calling this URL
http://localhost:7872/api/v1/tk103s?access-token=abcd

This is working great and returning data if and only if `access_token` matches with any **single user** in the table. 
I checked [QueryParamAuth](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/filters/auth/QueryParamAuth.php) class and found that `QueryParamAuth::authenticate()` returns `$identity` after successful authentication.

Currently this url is returning whole data of my table.

What I want is(after authentication):

1. Get user id/username of the requester.
2. Based on that id/username, the data related to him as per relations of tables in db. (currently whole rows are being returned but I want only few that are matching with the current requester/user)

I tried but didn't getting any clue to catch returned `$identity` of user after authentication. 
And I know it is possible too to make this work. Help me out folks to create magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Get user id/username of the requester.

That **user** instance you did return within the `findIdentityByAccessToken` method should be accessible any where inside your app within `Yii::$app->user->identity`. And should hold all the attributes retreived from DB. here is a quick example of using it to check access within the **checkAccess** method of the **ActiveController** class:

```
public function checkAccess($action, $model = null, $params = [])
{
    // only an image owner can request the related 'delete' or 'update' actions
    if ($action === 'update' or $action === 'delete') {
        if ($model->user_id !== \Yii::$app->user->identity->id)
            throw new \yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException('You can only '.$action.' images that you\'ve added.');
    }
}
```

Note that the `checkAccess` is by default an [empty method](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/rest/ActiveController.php#L132) that is manually called inside all the built-in actions in ActiveController. the Idea is to pass the action ID and the model instance to it just after retrieving it from DB and before modifying it so we can do extra checks. If you just need to perform checks by actions ID then [yii\filters\AccessControl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html) may be enough but inside `checkAccess` you are expecting to also get the model instance itself so it is important to note that when building your own actions or overriding existing onces. be sure to manually invoke it the same way it is done in [UpdateAction.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/rest/UpdateAction.php) or [DeleteAction.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/rest/DeleteAction.php).

---

> 2. whole rows are being returned but I want only few .. matching with .. current requester/user

It depends on how your data is structured. You can override ActiveController's **actions** to filter results before outputting them, it can be handled in the related **SearchModel** class if you are using one or it can be handled in **model**. A quick tip may be by simply overriding the **find** method inside your model:

```
public static function find()
{
    return parent::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->getId()]); // or Yii::$app->user->identity->id
}
```

Note that this works only when using [ActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html). Which means when using this:

```
$images = Image::find()->all();
```

The `find` method we just overriden will be filtered by default by always including that `where` condition before generating the DB query. Also note the default built-in **actions** in **ActiveController** are using ActiveRecords but if you are using actions where you are constructing the SQL queries using the [Query Builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html) then you should manually do the filtering.

The same can be done if using [ActiveQuery](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html) (maybe better explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948917/yii2-activequery-example-and-what-is-the-reason-to-generate-activequery-class)) by doing this:

```
public static function find()
{
    $query = new \app\models\Image(get_called_class());
    return $query->andWhere(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->getId()]);
}
```

Comment: Awesome dude.. Solution 1 worked for me as per my requirement. However, I'm not able to follow 2nd one. However I did find it's solution by creating a separate action and getting required data with activedataprovider.

Comment: I also need one more suggestion, Is it a good approach to check user's access in checkAccess() in controller? If it passes test then I will provide him data as per request otherwise reject it. Is it right approach? If not let me know the better one please..

Comment: checkAccess is powerful if you are invoking it where it should be. [RBAC](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#rbac) may also be an alternative. It always depends on what you are building. I just updated both answer parts. I hope it is better explained now.

Comment: one more thing. if you don't need to do the filtering in too many actions or if somewhere you do expect to get all images by invoking `Image::find()->all()` then creating a separate action with a separate activedataprovider as you did is a much better solution that the one I gave.

Comment: @Samel thanks for the reply. Now I think I'm being a bit more compatible with yii.