# Yii2 - replacement for beforeFind to optimize nested views in MySql

Tags: yii2

Yii1 used to have beforeFind method in which you could modify the query or whatever else you might want to do.

In Yii2 the suggested alternative is to use the modelQuery solution for example

```
class MyModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

  public static function find()
  {
      return new MyModelQuery(get_called_class());
  }
/* ... */
}
```

and

```
 class MyModelQuery extends \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 {
   public function init( )
   {
     /** do something here **/
   }
 }
```

But how do I pass or reference MyModel within MyModelQuery?
For example:-

```
class MyModelQuery extends \yii\db\ActiveQuery
{
   public function init( )
   {
     $sql = "SET @variable = {$MyModel->variable1}";
   }
 }
```

**EDIT**

For completeness, I've added a use case to help others in future.

I have nested views with group by's running under MySql and it runs VERY badly.

In my case, I have orders, order-items and order-item-fees tables, each one-to-many to the next and I want to sum the order totals. I have nested view, one at each level to sum to the level above, but at the order-item and order-item-fee levels MySql is grouping the whole table first (I cannot use algorithm=merge as I have a GROUP BY).

I'm implementing the Pushdown method where you define a SQL variable to use in sub-views to narrow down the search as outlined here: http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/views-better-performance-with-condition-pushdown
and also here
https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/05/19/a-workaround-for-the-performance-problems-of-temptable-views/

In this way, if I can add a 'WHERE order_id=' to the where clause of the two sub-views, I reduce a 3.5 second query down to 0.003 second query.

So using, Salem's suggestion below, I can execute a SQL statement 'SET @order_id=1234' before my query, which is then picked up in the order-item and order-item-fee views using a function.  Note: this is connection specific, so no danger of collisions between sessions.

A bit convoluted but fast.

It would be interesting, though, to see a performance comparison between SQL and looping in PHP perhaps....

EDIT 2

In fact, you normally use find() as a static method, so there is no way of using $this->order_id, so I changed this to over-ride the findOne method

```
public static function findOne( $orderId )
{
    if ( isset($orderId) )
    {
        $sql = "SET @orderId='{$orderId}'";
        Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
    }

    return parent::findOne( $orderId );
}
```

I also use this view with other searches, so in the view I need to check whether the orderId is set or not ...

```
where  (
        CASE 
        WHEN ( NOT isnull( get_session_orderId() ) )
          THEN `order`.order_id = get_session_cartref()
          ELSE `order`.order_id LIKE '%'
          END
          )
```

Comment: Can you provide  a specific  sample?  .. please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About how to involve an ActiveQuery class check my answer here:

[Yii2 : ActiveQuery Example and what is the reason to generate ActiveQuery class separately in Gii?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948917/yii2-activequery-example-and-what-is-the-reason-to-generate-activequery-class)

But if what you are trying to do doesn't require building named scopes then you may simply override the find method by something like this:

```
public static function find()
{
    return parent::find()->where(['variable' => 'some value']);
}
```

Comment: though, you cannot use $this in a static context.  See EDIT2 above.

Comment: Oh yes you are right. I did a quick copy/past from a code where I was getting the value from `Yii::$app->user` class. I just edited my answer to not confuse others. thanks for pointing it out. another option may be by using a named scope with arguments like `big($threshold = 100)` in the example I linked but you steal need to do `Model::find()->big($value)` each time. I suggest to add your solution as an answer to this.

Comment: One last thing, in the example I linked there is a second part that shows how to use a modified query as a relational data method that we can use when doing eager loading. your case looks to be linking related models. did you try that instead of overriding the findOne method ? I'm asking this just because I'm curios if Yii2 will combine both queries in one before sending to DB. I'm not sure if it works the same way like in Yii1 due to the noSql DB support in Yii2. Anyway this may not solve your case I just asked because your question made me curios about it. I think I should try it myself :)

Comment: Hi Salem.  No, I'm using views rather than models and relations as I'm actually joining 8+ tables.  My model is looking at the view as if it were a table, setting tableName() and primaryKey() accordingly.  I like your named scope with a parameter but the findOne is working well, so haven't tried it.  I'll update my question with your suggestion...